# Does the wiggle bones add-on work in 3.0?

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, bones, versions

I created a simple two bone rig, and checked the wiggle bones box for each bone in pose mode. I moved a bone, but the other didn't jiggle. This is my only alternative to the soft body simulation, and I need this to work badly.

Comment: That's an external addon, not part of Blender so it's best to join the conversation about it [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/wiggle-bones-a-jiggle-bone-implementation-for-2-8/1154726). The last post from the author at the bottom of the thread was posted around 11 hours ago and the current version is downloadable from the first post in the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Wiggle Addon* does tell you when it is not enabled:
[image]

Make sure that *Wiggle Scene* and *Wiggle Armature* are enabled.

Wiggle Scene:
[image]

Wiggle Armature:
[image]